# (EloquentJavascript: Chapter 4) Reversing an array - is there anything wrong with my version?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is what I got when trying to solve the "reversing an array" excercise in the book. It's different to what's in the answers list, so I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my version?

```
  function revInPlace(array){
    var tempArr = [];
    for (i=array.length; i>0; i--){
      tempArr.push(array.pop());
    }
    array = tempArr;
    return array;
  }

  var range = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

  console.log(revInPlace(range));

  --> [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

What's given in the book as an answer is this (I also don't actually understand how this is working, so could someone also explain this code to me plox?):

```
  function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
      var old = array[i];
      array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
      array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
    }
    return array;
  }
```

Comment: You're not reversing the array in place, you're returning a new array. Try `console.log(range)` after you call your function.

Comment: Not only are you returning a new array, you also are emptying the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Technically your version doesn't actually reverse the array in place.  You create a new array `tempArr` such that in your case:

```
reversed = revInPlace(arr);
console.log(arr); // returns empty original array after popping all elements off
console.log(reversed === arr);  // returns false;
```

While your version does perform the reverse, it will be much slower due to the creation of a new array, popping and pushing of values.

Comment: I just realized that `console.log(arr)` will also show just `[]` because he popped everything off it during the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you're not doing the same reversing "in-place" since you need to create another array ...

while the code from the book does that, it does that by switching (in-place) between the first half and the end half of the array, just try the loop with 0 and 1 assuming an array of 5 elements :

```
// array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] ... i = 0
var old = array[i]; // array[0] is 1
array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i]; // array[0] = array[4] which is 5
array[array.length - 1 - i] = old; // array[4] = 1


// array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] ... i = 1
var old = array[i]; // array[1] is 2
array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i]; // array[1] = array[3] which is 4
array[array.length - 1 - i] = old; // array[3] = 2
```

the looping for length 5 will end up in here due `Math.floor(5 / 2)` is 2 since you're basically done with the whole array